# can't NULL-Terminate recv buffer

Tags: c++, tcp, null, network-programming, recv

trying to fix the problem from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136218/c-non-sense-data-between-recv-calls/

I've tried a lot of ways to null-terminate the `buf` from `recv`, before showing what i have tried, here is the code where i hook the `recv` function and i log it data:

```
typedef int (WINAPI *SendPtr)(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);
HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary("wsock32.dll");
SendPtr pSend = (SendPtr)GetProcAddress(hLib, "send");
int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);
SendPtr pRecv = (SendPtr)GetProcAddress(hLib, "recv");
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags);
extern HMODULE hDLL;
__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT WINAPI MyProcedure(int code, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
HMODULE g_hModule = NULL ;

INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    switch(Reason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

            CreateConsole();
            g_hModule = hDLL;
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hDLL);
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pSend, MySend);
            if(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)


            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pRecv, MyRecv);
            if(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)


            return TRUE;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


// ---------- SEND ------------


int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    int i = 0;
    int ret = pSend(s, buf, len, flags);
    while (i < ret && buf)
    {
        int len = strlen(buf) +1;
        buf += len;
        i += len;
    }


    return ret;
}

// ---------- RECV ------------

int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags)
{

    int i = 0;
    int ret = pRecv(s, buf, len, flags);

    while (i < ret && buf)
    {           
        cout<<buf<<endl;

        int len = strlen(buf) +1;
        buf += len;
        i += len;    
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**What have i tested**

I have tried checking the number of bytes of `buf` then adding the terminator:

```
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags)
    {

        int i = 0;
        int ret = pRecv(s, buf, len, flags);
        buf[ret] = '\0';

        while (i < ret && buf)
        {           
            cout<<buf<<endl;

            int len = strlen(buf) +1;
            buf += len;
            i += len;    
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The result? the data being corrupted to garbage data like `@ÿÿÿ^¡5~ç` and the program where i try to extract the data, crashing.

I have tried storing the data into a vector.

```
std::vector<char> buffer(1025);

int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags)
{

    int i = 0;
    int ret = pRecv(s, buffer.data(), buffer.size() - 1, 0);



    while (i < ret && buffer.data())
    {

        cout<<buffer.data()<<endl;

        int len = strlen(buffer.data()) +1;
        buf += len;
        i += len;

    }


    return ret;
}
```

Kind of works, stores some amount of data then the program crashes, changing the size of the vector don't works neither.

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop?

Comment: Also, what do you think happens if `pRecv` returns with an error?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I sometimes receive two packets or more at once which is like `packet1\0packet2` without that loop it only reads `packet1` ignoring the `packet2`

Comment: But you don't *read* in the loop. You also don't check for buffer overflows. And you shadow the argument `len` with the variable `len`.

Comment: When exactly do you think `buf` or `buffer.data()` will be null?

Comment: @molbdnilo The server sends null-terminated the data, except when it sends big amounts of data which when i receive it is splitted in a lot of recv calls, until i get the call which contains the null terminator.

Comment: @32bitsx86 That won't make the address of your receiving buffer suddenly become null. And TCP is a streaming protocol. There are no packets, and there's no guarantee that a `recv` will receive what was sent in one `send`. You need to reassemble your packet structure at the receiving end.

Answer (score 1):

With TCP...

You cannot treat arbitrary data from the network as if it is a string.   You need to establish a protocol that determines how data is formatted and when you have received an amount of data that you can make sense of.

Then you need to receive data off the network until you have gotten an amount of data that you can make sense of before trying to interpret it.

A trivial protocol for sending a string across TCP would be

```
[X = 32 bit network byte order unsigned int string length]
Next X bytes are the string
```

Then, after you get X + 4 bytes, you can interpret the data, starting at an offset of 4 bytes as being the string and either know that you included a nul terminator when you sent it, or put in a nul terminator on the client side at the end of the buffer.  Any data beyond that X + 4 bytes would be the start of the next string, or the client would disconnect if it is done sending data.

At that point you can print it.

If you want VERY raw debugging data, you can simply print out the hex value of each byte you receive like:

```
Recv returned 4 bytes:  0xa7 0x42 0x8b 0x44
```

each time receive returns, but that's not often that useful.